# What is the O time complexity for this algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, java

is the Big-O for this O(1) or some asymptotic like 1/n?

Saying that because if it defaults, the time limits at about 1000000 ns, but if it returns while in the loop, it is about a fraction of that. The time seems to increase very slightly as the inputs increase.

```
public static int[] call(int b, int c) {
    int[] f = new int[2];
    final double n = 1.13;

    for (int x = -100; x < 100; x++) {
        for (int y = -100; y < 100; y++) {
            if (((n+x)*(n+y)) == ((n*n)+(b*n)+c)) {
                f[0] = x;
                f[1] = y;
                return f;
            }
        }
    }
    return f;

    /* // timer method
     * long startTime = System.nanoTime() ;
     * call();
     * long endTime   = System.nanoTime() ;
     * long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
     * System.out.println(totalTime);
     * 
     *      f(2, 1)   : 499284
     *      f(4, 4)   : 487452
     *      f(6, 9)   : 501479
     *      f(8, 7)   : 493296 
     *      f(10, 21) : 500602
     *      f(12, 36) : 505862
     *      
     */

}
```

Also, please ignore that the code is wonky.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Comment: Since n = 1.13 is fixed, O (1) and O (1/n) are the same in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper bound doesn't get affected by inputs b & c so we can say it is $O(1)$.

Comment: Even though the time increases with inputs? Edit: Never mind, I misunderstood. Thank you!

Comment: That is because of early exit from the loop but while calculating upper bound consider the worst case.